# Trouble with serializationin Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a class I wrote called **Node**

And I need it to be serializable so it will go as an extra to an intent.

I get this error and I'm stumped.

> Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.rachel.MainActivity$Node)

This is the code:

```
class LineSeconds implements Serializable {
    String line;
    int seconds;

    public LineSeconds(String line, int seconds) {
        this.line = line;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }   
}

class Item implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<LineSeconds> list;
    String option1;
    String option2;
    int special;

    public Item(ArrayList<LineSeconds> list, String option1, String option2, int special) {
        this.list = list;
        this.option1 = option1;
        this.option2 = option2;
        this.special = special;
    }
}

class Node implements Serializable {
    Item key;
    Node left, right;
    int numWritten = 0;

    public Node(Item key, Node left, Node right) {
        this.key = key;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

And this is when I use serialization:

Where toRewind is a Node.
and numGoBackTo is an int.

```
finish();

Intent restart = new Intent(cont, MainActivity.class);
                                                            restart.putExtra("toRewind", toRewind);
                                                            restart.putExtra("numGoBackTo", numGoBackTo);
                                                            startActivity(restart);
```

Comment: Stack trace required.

Comment: I don't know what that is or how to get it for you.

Comment: stack trace is that error message you posted plus any additional messages that would indicate the line numbers or method or class names where the error was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think cont is your Contex variable so you forget to add cont at the end

cont.startActivity(restart)